# Safari 4 colours corrupted on multi-monitor set-up

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, safari, colors

I find that when using Safari 4 on a multi-display Mac set-up, the colors will become corrupted when scrolling the content view of the window. Banding is introduced and the foreground colours tend towards black:

[image]

This only seems to happen after login, and is fixed by moving the Safari window from one display to another and then back. Does anyone know of a more permanent solution? I'm on version 4.0.2 on Leopard.

Comment: Is it only Safari that is affected?

Comment: Yep - only Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in [Safari 4.0.3](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Safari_4_0_3).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related, but I've had some weird problems after I upgraded to Safari 4 as well. The colours can be fine, but when I scroll some of it turn more and more gray:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be related to a corrupted colour profile for that monitor. Firstly try opening up colorsync and checking your profiles for errors.

If that doesn't work you should try opening up displays and creating new colour profiles for both your monitors and delete the old ones.

There might be some tips in this [forum](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2032159&start=0&tstart=0) as it sounds related.

Comment: I tried using the default Apple RGB profile on both displays, and also creating a new profile for each display. But the problem persists. I'll check out the forum.

Comment: Repair permissions (as suggested in the forum thread) did also not fix the issue.